# Right way to update Memcached value Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, memcached

What is the right way to update my key/value when the database is updated ? First i am finding all of the boots but later i am adding 10 more boots. How should i update the value of my key/value pair when my `if statement` is `!result`. After the first time i will always have `true` there but the table data might be changed in that time. Red a lot of materials but didn't find the right way.

```
$mem = new \Memcached();
$mem->addServer("localhost", 11211);

$result = $mem->get("boots");

if(!$result){
    $boots = Product::find()->where('active=1')->asArray()->all();
    $mem->set("boots", $boots);
}

$result = $mem->get("boots");
var_dump($result);die;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using direct Memcached objects instead of [cache component](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-memcache.html)?

Comment: No. I am just very new in all that memcached stuff and i don't know the right way obviously :/

Comment: I am strugling on the update data. If i check everytime the database to see is there a new record the benefits of the caching are lost. Am i right ?

Comment: See the [Query Caching](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html#query-caching) and [Cache Dependencies](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html#cache-dependencies) to get help with this case.